# SPFx remove (per project) node_modules and typings directory

Tags: spfx-tooling

I am working on smaller, but faster SSD drives, so every Megabyte hurts.

We are also used to zipping up entire projects and mailing it to developers costing half my rate

If I run the command

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

It kindly adds 318 Megabytes I do not want in my projectfolder

[image]

**Can these be moved?**

Comment: Nope this is how npm works. A similar question for angular 2 since angular 2 also uses npm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718690/huge-number-of-files-generated-for-every-angularjs-2-project. The final deployment files will be bundled and will be very few.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of NPM! This is unfortunately how it works and depending on the modules you download and their dependencies you will get even more once you start building larger projects.

Also have you looked at Nuget and the `packages` folders on a classic simple SharePoint Add-in.

Comment: Nuget...No, I was trained by the late Patrick van Tisseghem a long time ago, then never touched Visual Studio again (not because of Patrick) I did ASP even longer ago, only saw a future in Front-End stuff

Comment: Can Spfx toolling deal with symbolic links? That would save some diskspace

Comment: Yes, you can do that and also npm has a feature `npm link` that could be used. But..you can't do that on the whole `node_modules` folder as all projects use different modules.